# Can't get .htaccess work a second time

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to protect my .php file with .htaccess so no one can generate keys.
I already used .htaccess for /phpmyadmin/ but I can't get it to work a second time for the .php file. My php file located in /var/www/html/generateserial.php.
I added the .htaccess file in the same directory and hided the .htpasswd in /etc/.htpasswd.

Here is the content of .htaccess

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files /var/www/html/generateserial.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

I can't get it to work, but the .htaccess that works with /phpmyadmin/ has no problems.

If anyone could help me, It would be really appreciated. :)
dublo

Comment: tryied changing place of the .htpasswd and still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

i would do it this way putting the files block inside a directory block

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  <Files generateserial.php>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Files>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Comment: "seem to"? what does that mean?

Comment: I tryied with ip too like allow from 55.555.55.223 and it doesnt work